# Another way of checking youtube links?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, httpwebrequest

I am creating an application which will check for broken links in content.

All working apart from you tube links where I get a mixed response, broken links (or codes I have just made up) sometime come up with 200 ok and sometimes they come up as broken.

Is there a different way of checking broken links in youtube?

Im using standard .net/c# code

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(match.Groups[1].ToString()) as HttpWebRequest;
    //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    //Getting the Web Response.
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    //Returns TRUE if the Status code == 200
    // result = "true";
    result = response.StatusDescription;

    response.Close();
    // return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
catch
{
    //Any exception will returns false.
    result = "false";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> sometime come up with 200 ok and sometimes they come up as broken.

What you are doing is similar to web crawler, youtube will definitely have an anti-crawler mechanism, so if you have been accessing the link uninterrupted, your access may be blocked. In order to reduce the probability of this situation, you can reduce the frequency of visits and simulating the request of real users to visit the site as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

```
if(match.Groups[1].ToString().Contains(@"\n"))
{
  //....
}
```